# Looking for Java wrapper for curl library

Tags: java, curl, openssl, bouncycastle, fips

I am looking for Java wrapper for curl. I understand Java has excellent apis for http and https connections (i.e. standard as well as Apache http client).
I have a scenario where my https connections need to go through FIPS certified crypto engine. As Openssl is one that passed FIPS validation and curl uses it as its backend, I am wondering if there is an easy to use wrapper around curl lib.

The Bouncycastle crypto that ships with android is not fips certified.

Comment: How about [this](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android)?

Answer (score 7):

There is [curl-java](http://svwe10.itex.at/curl/curl-java/), which should be what you need, plus some instructions for it in [this blog post](http://chimpler.blogspot.fi/2009/03/logging-to-ebay-with-java-curl.html) and some improvements to the code in [java-curl-jar project](http://code.google.com/p/java-curl-jar/).

Comment: I briefly looked at it before this post. It is quite rudimentary. I am wondering if there is one that emulates URLConnection class.

Comment: @videoguy you probably should've specified that in the question :) Not aware of any, at least.